# Примитивная нейронная сеть работает некорректно

Tags: c++, нейронные-сети

написал примитивную нейронную сеть без скрытых слоев. На вход дается два числа, но ответ зависит только от первого: если первый элемент равен 1, то и результатом должна быть единица, если 0, то 0.
В итоге после обучения нейронная сеть далеко не всегда дает правильный результат.
Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h> 
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

// Summary value in neuron
float NeuronSum(float input[2], float weights[2],float bweight) {
    float result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
        result += input[i] * weights[i];
    }
    result += 1.0 * bweight;
    return result;
}
float ActivateFunction(float x) {
    return 1/(1+pow(2.72,-x));
}
float ActivateFunctionDerivative(float x) {
    return ActivateFunction(x) * (1-ActivateFunction(x));
}
// ai result
float aiRes(float input[2], float weights[2],float bweight) {
    return ActivateFunction( NeuronSum(input, weights, bweight) );
}

int main() {
    /*-----------Neural network--------------------------------
    -------------STRUCTURE:------------------------------------
    * - input neuron, # - hidden neuron, @ - output neuron 
    -----------------------------------------------------------
        *
        *   @
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    */


    srand(time(0));

    float imput[4][2] = {{1,0}, {0,0}, {0,1}, {1,1}};
    float output[4] = {1,0,0,1};
    float weights[2];
    float speed = 0.3;
    float error;
    float result;
    float rawResult;
    // bias weight
    float bweight = (float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX) * 2 - 1;
    for (int weight = 0; weight < 2; weight++) {
        weights[weight] = (float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX) * 2 - 1;
    }

    for (int epoch = 1; epoch <= 2000; epoch++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            rawResult = NeuronSum(imput[i], weights, bweight);
            result = aiRes(imput[i], weights, bweight);
            error = output[i] - result;
            for (int mask = 0; mask < 2; mask++) {
                weights[mask] = weights[mask] + error*ActivateFunctionDerivative(rawResult) * result * speed;
            }
            bweight = bweight + error * ActivateFunctionDerivative(rawResult) * result * speed;
        }
    } 
    float test[2] = {1,0};
    cout << aiRes(test, weights, bweight) << endl;
    if (aiRes(test, weights, bweight) > 0.5) {
        cout << "I think answer is 1!";
    } else {
        cout << "I think answer is 0!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот с проверкой(оценкой) на обучающем наборе:

```
/* 
 * File:   main.cpp
 * Author: papa
 *
 * Created on 19 октября 2020 г., 6:30
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

// Summary value in neuron
float NeuronSum(float input[2], float weights[2], float bweight)
{
    float result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        result += input[i] * weights[i];
    }
    result += 1.0 * bweight;
    return result;
}
float ActivateFunction(float x)
{
    return 1 / (1 + pow(2.72, -x));
}
float ActivateFunctionDerivative(float x)
{
    return ActivateFunction(x) * (1 - ActivateFunction(x));
}
// ai result
float aiRes(float input[2], float weights[2], float bweight)
{
    return ActivateFunction(NeuronSum(input, weights, bweight));
}

int main()
{

    /*-----------Neural network--------------------------------
    -------------STRUCTURE:------------------------------------
    * - input neuron, # - hidden neuron, @ - output neuron 
    -----------------------------------------------------------
        *
        *   @
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    */

    srand(time(0));

    float imput[4][2] = {{1, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}};
    float output[4] = {1, 0, 0, 1};
    float weights[2];
    float speed = 0.3;
    float error;
    float result;
    float rawResult;
    // bias weight
    float bweight = (float)rand() / (float)(RAND_MAX)*2 - 1;
    for (int weight = 0; weight < 2; weight++)
    {
        weights[weight] = (float)rand() / (float)(RAND_MAX)*2 - 1;
    }

    for (int epoch = 1; epoch <= 2000; epoch++)
    {
        float gl_error = 0;
        printf("ep: %d ", epoch);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            //            rawResult = NeuronSum(imput[i], weights, bweight);  // лишний прямой проход для однослойного
            result = aiRes(imput[i], weights, bweight);
            error = output[i] - result;
            for (int mask = 0; mask < 2; mask++)
            {
                weights[mask] = weights[mask] + error * ActivateFunctionDerivative(rawResult) * imput[i][mask] * speed;
            }
            bweight = bweight + error * ActivateFunctionDerivative(rawResult) * 1 * speed;
            gl_error += (error * error) / 2;
            printf("error: %f\n", gl_error);

            //      if (gl_error < 0.001)
            //          break;
        }
    }
    float test[2] = {1, 0};
    cout << aiRes(test, weights, bweight) << endl;
    if (aiRes(test, weights, bweight) > 0.5)
    {
        cout << "I think answer is 1!"<<endl;;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "I think answer is 0!"<<endl;;
    }

    for (int single_array_ind = 0; single_array_ind < 4; single_array_ind++)
    {

        float *inputs;
        float output_1_layer;
        inputs = imput[single_array_ind];
        output_1_layer = aiRes(inputs, weights, bweight);
        bool equal_flag = 0;
        float elem_train_out = 0;
        // for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++)
        // {
        float elem_net = 0;
        elem_net = output_1_layer;
        elem_train_out = output[single_array_ind];

        if (elem_net > 0.5)
            elem_net = 1;
        else
            elem_net = 0;

        printf("elem: %f", elem_net);
        printf("elem tr out: %f", elem_train_out);

        if (elem_net == elem_train_out)
            equal_flag = 1;
        else
        {
            equal_flag = 0;
            break;
        }
        // }
        if (equal_flag == 1)
            printf("-vecs are equal-\n");
        else
            printf("-vecs are not equal-\n");

        printf("========\n");
    }
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}


error: 0.000122
error: 0.000155
ep: 1998 error: 0.000015
error: 0.000089
error: 0.000122
error: 0.000155
ep: 1999 error: 0.000015
error: 0.000089
error: 0.000122
error: 0.000155
ep: 2000 error: 0.000015
error: 0.000089
error: 0.000122
error: 0.000155
0.994562
I think answer is 1!
elem: 1.000000elem tr out: 1.000000-vecs are equal-
========
elem: 0.000000elem tr out: 0.000000-vecs are equal-
========
elem: 0.000000elem tr out: 0.000000-vecs are equal-
========
elem: 1.000000elem tr out: 1.000000-vecs are equal-
========
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так)

```
/* 
 * File:   main.cpp
 * Author: papa
 *
 * Created on 19 октября 2020 г., 6:30
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <time.h> 
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

// Summary value in neuron
float NeuronSum(float input[2], float weights[2],float bweight) {
    float result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
        result += input[i] * weights[i];
    }
    result += 1.0 * bweight;
    return result;
}
float ActivateFunction(float x) {
    return 1/(1+pow(2.72,-x));
}
float ActivateFunctionDerivative(float x) {
    return ActivateFunction(x) * (1-ActivateFunction(x));
}
// ai result
float aiRes(float input[2], float weights[2],float bweight) {
    return ActivateFunction( NeuronSum(input, weights, bweight) );
}

int main() {
    /*-----------Neural network--------------------------------
    -------------STRUCTURE:------------------------------------
    * - input neuron, # - hidden neuron, @ - output neuron 
    -----------------------------------------------------------
        *
        *   @
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    */


    srand(time(0));

    float imput[4][2] = {{1,0}, {0,0}, {0,1}, {1,1}};
    float output[4] = {1,0,0,1};
    float weights[2];
    float speed = 0.3;
    float error;
    float result;
    float rawResult;
    // bias weight
    float bweight = (float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX) * 2 - 1;
    for (int weight = 0; weight < 2; weight++) {
        weights[weight] = (float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX) * 2 - 1;
    }

    for (int epoch = 1; epoch <= 2000; epoch++) {
        float gl_error = 0;   
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
//            rawResult = NeuronSum(imput[i], weights, bweight);  // лишний прямой проход для однослойного
            result = aiRes(imput[i], weights, bweight);
            error = output[i] - result;
            for (int mask = 0; mask < 2; mask++) {
                weights[mask] = weights[mask] + error*ActivateFunctionDerivative(rawResult) * imput[i][mask] * speed;
            }
            bweight = bweight + error * ActivateFunctionDerivative(rawResult) * 1 * speed;
        gl_error+= (error * error) / 2;
        printf("error: %f\n", gl_error);
        
        //if (gl_error < 0.001)
        //    break;
        }
    } 
    float test[2] = {1,0};
    cout << aiRes(test, weights, bweight) << endl;
    if (aiRes(test, weights, bweight) > 0.5) {
        cout << "I think answer is 1!";
    } else {
        cout << "I think answer is 0!";
    }
}



ep: 1954 error: 0.000007
ep: 1955 error: 0.000007
ep: 1956 error: 0.000007
ep: 1957 error: 0.000007
ep: 1958 error: 0.000006
ep: 1959 error: 0.000006
ep: 1960 error: 0.000006
ep: 1961 error: 0.000006
ep: 1962 error: 0.000006
ep: 1963 error: 0.000006
ep: 1964 error: 0.000006
ep: 1965 error: 0.000006
ep: 1966 error: 0.000006
ep: 1967 error: 0.000006
ep: 1968 error: 0.000006
ep: 1969 error: 0.000006
ep: 1970 error: 0.000006
ep: 1971 error: 0.000006
ep: 1972 error: 0.000006
ep: 1973 error: 0.000006
ep: 1974 error: 0.000006
ep: 1975 error: 0.000006
ep: 1976 error: 0.000006
ep: 1977 error: 0.000006
ep: 1978 error: 0.000006
ep: 1979 error: 0.000006
ep: 1980 error: 0.000006
ep: 1981 error: 0.000006
ep: 1982 error: 0.000006
ep: 1983 error: 0.000006
ep: 1984 error: 0.000006
ep: 1985 error: 0.000006
ep: 1986 error: 0.000006
ep: 1987 error: 0.000006
ep: 1988 error: 0.000006
ep: 1989 error: 0.000006
ep: 1990 error: 0.000006
ep: 1991 error: 0.000006
ep: 1992 error: 0.000006
ep: 1993 error: 0.000006
ep: 1994 error: 0.000006
ep: 1995 error: 0.000006
ep: 1996 error: 0.000006
ep: 1997 error: 0.000006
ep: 1998 error: 0.000006
ep: 1999 error: 0.000006
ep: 2000 error: 0.000006
0.996478
I think answer is 1!
```

Comment: Был лишний проход, и исправил в коррекции весов, там появились входные сигналы как imput[i][mask] и с биасом как 1.

Answer (score 1):

Кому интересно, я сделал функцию для разных функций активации на Python и другого, можно переписать на любой язык и управлять посредством числовых кодов(типа байт-коды),можно вставлять на однослойную сеть)Производная функции будет число функции + 1 :)

```
TRESHOLD_FUNC = 0
TRESHOLD_FUNC_DERIV = 1
SIGMOID = 2
SIGMOID_DERIV = 3
RELU = 4
RELU_DERIV = 5
TAN = 6
TAN_DERIV = 7
INIT_W_MY = 8
INIT_W_RANDOM = 9
LEAKY_RELU = 10
LEAKY_RELU_DERIV = 11
INIT_W_CONST = 12
INIT_RANDN = 13
SOFTMAX = 14
SOFTMAX_DERIV = 15
PIECE_WISE_LINEAR = 16
PIECE_WISE_LINEAR_DERIV = 17
MODIF_MSE = 18

ready = False

# Различные операции по числовому коду


def operations(op, x):
    global ready
    alpha_leaky_relu = 1.7159
    alpha_sigmoid = 1
    alpha_tan = 1.7159
    beta_tan = 2/3
    if op == RELU:
        if (x <= 0):
            return 0
        else:
            return x
    elif op == RELU_DERIV:
        if (x <= 0):
            return 0
        else:
            return 1
    elif op == TRESHOLD_FUNC:
        if (x > 0):
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    elif op == TRESHOLD_FUNC_DERIV:
        return 1
    elif op == LEAKY_RELU:
        if (x <= 0):
            return alpha_leaky_relu
        else:
            return 1
    elif op == LEAKY_RELU_DERIV:
        if (x <= 0):
            return alpha_leaky_relu
        else:
            return 1
    elif op == SIGMOID:
        y = 1 / (1 + math.exp(-alpha_sigmoid * x))
        return y
    elif op == SIGMOID_DERIV:
        y = 1 / (1 + math.exp(-alpha_sigmoid * x))
        return alpha_sigmoid * y * (1 - y)
    elif op == PIECE_WISE_LINEAR:
        if x >= 1/2:
            return 1
        elif x <1/2 and x > -1/2:
           return x
        elif x<= 1/2:
            return 0      
    elif op == PIECE_WISE_LINEAR_DERIV:
        if x < 1/2 and x > -1/2:
           return 1
        else:
            return 1     
    elif op == INIT_W_MY:
        if ready:
            ready = False
            return -0.567141530112327
        ready = True
        return 0.567141530112327
    elif op == INIT_W_RANDOM:

        return random.random()
    elif op == TAN:
        y = alpha_tan * math.tanh(beta_tan * x)
        return y
    elif op == TAN_DERIV:
        return beta_tan * alpha_tan * 4 / ((math.exp(beta_tan * x) + math.exp(-beta_tan * x))**2)
    elif op == INIT_W_CONST:
        return 0.567141530112327
    elif op == INIT_RANDN:
        return np.random.randn()
    else:
        print("Op or function does not support ", op)
```